# Can insert our custom data of places in google places api?

Tags: google-places-api

Many of you has worked on LBS application in android and also used the Google Places API web service for the information of various places. And you may also noticed that the data for India specifically is not accurate means many of places that you know are not their on the map.

So my question is that is there any way that you can add your database to Google's Places API Web service in the form of XML/JSON? If yes then please let me know how it is possible.

Have a great day ahead!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Places [add requests](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#adding_a_place) :

> Place Report requests are used to add new Places, or delete existing ones. New Places will be available immediately in Place Searches initiated by your application, and will enter the moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added Place will not be available to other applications until it has been approved by the moderation process.
>
> Places that have been added by your application can also be deleted, until they have been moderated. Once moderated and added into the full Place Search results, a Place can no longer be deleted. Places that are not accepted by the moderation process will continue to be visible to the application that submitted them.

---

```
POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true_or_false&key=api_key HTTP/1.1

Host: maps.googleapis.com

{
  "location": {
    "lat": -33.8669710,
    "lng": 151.1958750
  },
  "accuracy": 50,
  "name": "Google Shoes!",
  "types": ["shoe_store"],
  "language": "en-AU"
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have been trying to add places with the places api, but they are not showing up on my nearby search. The place was created successfully but still doesn't show. Have you had any problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

(from: [Google Places API : Add Place Privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845740/google-places-api-add-place-privacy))

The Place Add has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add).