# GoogleMaps API: is it possible to add places that only your app can see?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291557/can-insert-our-custom-data-of-places-in-google-places-api) but as far as I understand this means the place/location becomes available to everyone.  Can I add places that only my web-app will see? And perhaps allow some places to be seen only by certain users ... ?

Also - what is the thing with the API key: I did not notice any recent talk about it, but I understood that you have to use one now. Am I correct?

One last thing: how customizable this API really is? Can I add/remove places and their descriptions and perhaps make places custom-clickable (I see you can add markers etc [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)? I only started digging into GoogleMaps API so I am rushing this a bit, but answers would be very helpful so I can kickstart my developing.

Comment: 1) Yes you need an API key. 2) If you need places available only in your app, you can store them in your own db. Please define *make places custom-clickable*.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. storing in my db sounds good enough, great actually. by custom-clickable I mean that each marker has some kind of id and by clicking on it I can probably call some functions etc ?

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that.

Comment: If you post all of this and perhaps some examples as an answer I might mark it as correct if you would ? :)